# Dynamic Load(dlopen) shared libraries(.so files) from zip file

Tags: c, dll, linker, dlopen

For special reasons, my shared libraries (.so files) have to be zipped into .zip file for C uses.

Is it possible to dynamic load(dlopen or invoke) the shared libraries (.so) files form .zip file for C code without changing the dynamic linker?

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. Any reason you add the C++11 tag for a C question? C++ is a different language.

Comment: my .so files is zipped up. Under this scenario, is it still possible to dlopen or invoke the functions my .so file ?

Comment: [m1m1x/memdlopen](https://github.com/m1m1x/memdlopen) shows that it's possible *in theory* to modify `dlopen` behavior by livepatching libc, but in general I would say: no, there is no reliable way to do this. Even Android unzips `.so` files at installation time instead of loading them from the `.apk` at runtime, and they have full control of their own runtime and linker...

Comment: @ephemient Android started doing exactly that in api level 23. https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/android-n-mr2-preview-1/android-changes-for-ndk-developers.md#opening-shared-libraries-directly-from-an-apk

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to dynamic load(dlopen or invoke) the shared libraries (.so) files form .zip file for C code without changing the dynamic linker?

No.

IFF your libraries are stored in the `.zip` uncompressed, then a patch to GLIBC to implement `dlopen_with_offset()` is not too hard (we do have such a local patch, there are few gotcha's to watch out for, this still requires modifying the dynamic linker).

This [feature request](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=11767) is also relevant.